# Use VBA to enforce specific date format entry on a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to enforce a specific date format on a sheet where dates will be manually entered or pasted on a regular basis. Since Excel's built-in data validation does not work for pasted values, I am trying to accomplish this with VBA.

This is the code I have written/hodgepodged together from other Stack posts:

```
Option Explicit
Function dateCheck(cellval As Date) As Boolean
    If IsDate(cellval) And cellval.NumberFormat <> "yyyy-dd-mm" Then
        MsgBox "Please use the yyyy-dd-mm date format!"
        dateCheck = True
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim A As Boolean
    
    'rule 1: column A allows only text length up to 9
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("collection_dates"))
    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In AffectedCells
            A = dateCheck(Cell.Value)
            If A = True Then
               Application.Undo 'undo insert
               Exit Sub 'stop checking after one invalid data was found.
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

"collection_dates" is a range of cells I named, which I want to enforce formatting on.

The error I'm currently getting is a "Run-time error '13': type mismatch" on the line `A = dateCheck(Cell.Value)`
I have tried various other iterations of this and gotten various other errors; I think I am just fundamentally missing something about how to properly validate a cell value in VBA.

Comment: `dateCheck` is expecting a Date so what happens if `Cell.Value` is not a Date?  Also `cellval.NumberFormat` - a cell has a NumberFormat but a Date does not.

Comment: Also - if the cell has a date and the NumberFormat isn't correct then you can just correct it in your code without asking the user to do it...

Comment: Would your process allow for use of custom cell formatting (ctrl+1 number>custom 'yyyy-dd-mm;) in your "collection_dates" range so number values, pasted or entered, _appear_  as required?  And then just check to ensure that numbers are entered?  Or does the underlying value actually have to be in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format?  I've yet to see an application that won't allow dates to be formatted as required given a valid date input.

Comment: TimWilliams - I think this is what I was missing - you can call dateCheck on a value but you have to call NumberFormat on a cell.

C.George - That's a good point - as long as a valid date is entered in the first place, the format can be corrected. The main purpose of this is to prevent dates that are completely mistyped. I'll give it a shot without the numberFormat. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advice from some of the comments and stopped attempting to enforce the formatting at this level, since what was really important to me was that dates were entered correctly, ie. not typos.

I had to make some changes to accommodate blank cells or else the Application.Undo would loop endlessly if an incorrect value was entered and cleared. This is the final product, which appears to be working:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    'rule 1: only allow dates to be entered in affected cells
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("collection_dates"))
    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In AffectedCells
            If Not IsDate(Cell.Value) Then
                If Trim(Cell.Value) = "" Then
                    GoTo DoNothing
                Else
                    MsgBox "Please enter a valid date!", vbCritical
                    Application.Undo 'undo insert
                    Exit Sub 'stop checking after one invalid data was found.
                End If
            End If
        DoNothing:
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```